# Apache - htaccess 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm learning how to make PHP MVC applications, and the tutorial I followed involved creating two `.htaccess` files - one to prevent a user from navigating to the application folders and files; the other to rewrite how the URL is presented in order for me to parse and retrieve controllers, methods and parameters.

When deploying these files on my XAMPP server, they work correctly. However, when deploying these files on to my university server via FTP, the `500 Internal Server Error` appears, and removing these files will allow me to see my application. But I need these files otherwise I can't call the appropriate controllers, models and views.

I have searched around for the answer, and many solutions say that there could be syntax errors, which I don't believe I have any as it works on the XAMPP instance just fine. The other answers were that the server itself may not be configured to allow me to upload such files or something similar.

I do not have access to the configuration of my university's server, which I know may hinder any solutions you could provide to me. So, if there are any PHP solutions to ***at least*** let me parse the URL the way I need to, I'll be happy to drop the `.htaccess` files.

The first `.htaccess` file, located within the app directory of the application:

```
Options -Indexes
```

The second `.htaccess` file; located within the public directory of my application:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /~21249593/Internet_Technologies/Element_2/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The PHP class used to parse the URL to call the appropriate controller and its method, I have posted the full logic so you can understand *how* the parsing works:

```
class App {
    protected $controller = 'home';
    protected $method = 'index';
    protected $params = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $url = $this->parseUrl();

        if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }

        require_once '../app/controllers/' . $this->controller . '.php';

        $this->controller = new $this->controller;

        if (isset($url[1])) {
            if (method_exists($this->controller, $url[1])) {
                $this->method = $url[1];
                unset($url[1]);
            }
        }

        $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : array();

        call_user_func_array([$this->controller, $this->method], $this->params);
    }

    public function parseUrl() {
        if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
            return $url = explode('/', filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'], '/'), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help you can give me here

**EDIT**

I should've stated that XAMPP is using 2.4.9 Apache, the FTP is 2.2.3

Comment: Are the versions (Apache, PHP) the same on your XAMPP as on your university FTP?

Comment: Do you have mode rewrite turned on at your FTP server? if not then try to enable it, usually by executing the command `a2enmod rewrite` and then don't forget to restart your web server instance.

Furthermore, you need to check the error logs to see what is exactly getting wrong.

Comment: @anubhava the htaccess file is not located at the root of the site, the root is /~21249593/

Comment: @TomHart Sorry, should've stated that, FTP server is Apache is 2.2.3, XAMPP is 2.4.9.

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash I wouldn't know, I don't know the configurations of this server, all we do is simply upload to it.

Comment: @anubhava doesn't make a difference, the mere existence of either files causes the error.

Comment: what's the content of the server error? (from apache error logs)

Comment: @Ma'moonAl-Akash your suggestion didn't work, I'm afraid

Comment: @eis no access to logs, at least I don't think I do.

Comment: Check your web server's error log, let us know what it contains

Comment: @RoyalSwish have you confirmed from administration that there is no access to error logs?

Comment: if the mere existance of the files gives an error, you probably don't have permissions to use such files in your university account. You might or might not have access to change that. If it's a shared environment, then you probably don't.

Comment: If you don't have access to change the configuration and you're not allowed to do this without that change, there is not much you can do except use not-so-clean urls that don't have mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: @eis I will contact them and see, but I'm guessing permissions is the problem too. Would you know how I could parse the URL the way I need it to be done with PHP? At least I can call my controllers and methods that way.

Comment: @RoyalSwish like I said, you can use urls like `index.php?url=something` and your code should work pretty much as-is. For cleaner urls you would need a server configuration change.

Comment: @eis Okay, thanks for your help, I will change back to normal `GET` urls. I'm currently not at home to work on this issue, so I will have to check this later. Much appreciated

Comment: "the mere existence of either files causes the error". But if you change `RewriteBase /` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does seem mod_rewrite or .htaccess usage in general is forbidden for your account. You should ask your administration if that can be changed, if not, you cannot use mod_rewrite urls.

What you can anyway do is to use urls like `http://yourdomain/index.php?url=something`, those should work regardless. For anything "cleaner" you would need a server configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't rewrite the URL you have to change the links to your application to the format your application needs them.

So insteaf of linking to mydomain.com/controller/method/param1/param2... you need to link to mydomain.com/index.php?url=controller/method/param1/param2..

The links are not that pretty anymore, but they will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 'Encoding' of '.htaccess' file. It worked for me. I used ANSI.